# Sort multidimensional array by value that is combinded with stdClass Object

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting

Fund few functions to sort array but none of them can sort them if they are  stdClass Object or ad least I could not find the right one

I need to sort this array by ordering value

```
 [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 12
                            [name] => Title1
                            [ordering] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 14
                            [name] => Title2
                            [ordering] => 3
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [name] => Title4
                            [ordering] => 2
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 22
                            [name] => Title5
                            [ordering] => 4
                        )

                )
```

any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a custom sorting function based on `ordering` field of your objects, then pass it in with usort.

[docs for usort](http://php.net/usort)

```
function sortByOrdering($obj1, $obj2) {
   return $obj2->ordering - $obj1->ordering;
}

usort($input['data'], 'sortByOrdering');
```

Note that you don't need to reassign `$input = usort(...)` as the array is referenced inside `usort`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, SiGanteng!  That's just what I was looking for.

I noted that the resulting sort order was descending. I was able to reverse that with a simple change to your function - I swapped $obj1 and $obj2 on the return statement:

```
return $obj1->ordering - $obj2->ordering;
```

In my application, the array data was:

```
Array
(
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 3
            [name] => Salesperson
            [slug] => 01-salesperson
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_order] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 3
            [taxonomy] => skill
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 6
            [object_id] => 53
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 5
            [name] => Airport Security
            [slug] => 02-airport-security
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_order] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 5
            [taxonomy] => skill
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 30
            [object_id] => 575
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 4
            [name] => Baker
            [slug] => 03-baker
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_order] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 4
            [taxonomy] => skill
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 28
            [object_id] => 453
        )
)
```

Using the above data, I needed to resort array $skills_nav in ascending order by "slug" value. Here's the final code which accomplished the task:

```
function sortByOrdering($obj1, $obj2) {
   return $obj1->slug - $obj2->slug;
}
usort($skills_nav, 'sortByOrdering');
```

To further explain to the reader, the two arguments expected by function sortByOrdering are automatically supplied by USORT.  This is explained by the [USORT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function in the manual.